# "klein Häschen" or "kleines Häschen"?

Tags: adjective, gender

There is a children's song called "Klein Häschen wollt' spazieren gehn". And it's the first line of the song as well.

"Häschen" is a neuter noun, so shouldn't it be "Kleines Häschen" instead?

Comment: This is partly a song,, partly a nursery rhyme, and partly a finger game, something like "Itsy Bitsy Spider" in the US. If you're not familiar with it, try [this Liederkiste video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BaIq2Eps6k). You can also find videos showing the finger movements. Nothing do to with the question, but some cultural background.

Comment: The song is probably old and doesnt have the Same german grammar rules than we have nowerdays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In today's standard German and with "klein" used as an adjective, you're completely right.

100 years ago, it was more common to use "klein" undeclined in this way, kind of an in-between between an adjective, a compound word part and a name part.

Note that the article is also missing: "Klein Häschen" is used like a name for a particular little hare here, it's different from "ein kleines Häschen" in that respect.

There was a series of jokes about a little girl "klein Erna", there is an old children's song with the lyrics "Hänschen klein / ging allein / in die weite Welt hinein...", there's the fictional stereotypical example of a small village called "Kleinkleckersdorf", and there are many real villages with a name starting with "Klein-".

So it's no surprise to find this in an old children's song.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the examples of this phenomenon!

Comment: Charles Dickens *Little Dorrit* also received the title *Klein Dorrit* in a translation dating from 1927, so 100 years seems a pretty exact range.